# Multiple errors when compiling wxWidgets with gcc 4.8.1

Tags: gcc, compilation, mingw, wxwidgets, mingw32

I've been trying for a while now compile wxWidgets library for Code::Blocks and I am still getting a lot of different errors.

My gcc verions is: `gcc (tdm-2) 4.8.1` and I want to build newest wxWidgets: [3.1.0](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/tag/v3.1.0). I've tried 3 different sources and each time I have some error (sometimes this same, sometimes different). I am working on Windows 8.1.

1. [[1]](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=41291#p166966)`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc UNICODE=1 MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1 BUILD=debug CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11"`
   and the error output:

> ```
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp: In function 'int wxVsprintf(wchar_t*, const wxString
> &, va_list)':
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:623:47: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t
> *' to 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
>      return wxCRT_VsprintfW(str, format.wc_str(), argptr);
>                                                ^
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:623:56: error: cannot convert 'va_list {aka char*}' t
> o 'const wchar_t*' for argument '3' to 'int vswprintf(wchar_t*, size_t, const wc
> har_t*, char*)'
>      return wxCRT_VsprintfW(str, format.wc_str(), argptr);
>                                                         ^
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:632:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void funct
> ion [-Wreturn-type]
>  }
>  ^
> makefile.gcc:6786: recipe for target 'gcc_mswuddll\monodll_wxcrt.o' failed
> mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswuddll\monodll_wxcrt.o] Error 1
> ```

2. [[2]](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW#Build_the_library)`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug` and the error output:

> ```
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp: In function 'int wxVsprintf(wchar_t*, const wxString
> &, va_list)':
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:623:47: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t
> *' to 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
>      return wxCRT_VsprintfW(str, format.wc_str(), argptr);
>                                                ^
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:623:56: error: cannot convert 'va_list {aka char*}' t
> o 'const wchar_t*' for argument '3' to 'int vswprintf(wchar_t*, size_t, const wc
> har_t*, char*)'
>      return wxCRT_VsprintfW(str, format.wc_str(), argptr);
>                                                         ^
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:632:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void funct
> ion [-Wreturn-type]
>  }
>  ^
> makefile.gcc:11860: recipe for target 'gcc_mswuddll\basedll_wxcrt.o' failed
> mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswuddll\basedll_wxcrt.o] Error 1
> ```

3. [[3]](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Compiling_wxWidgets_3.0.0_to_develop_Code::Blocks_(MSW)#Building_wxWidgets)`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=1 USE_OPENGL=1 VENDOR=cb CXXFLAGS="-fno-keep-inline-dllexport"1` and the error:

> ```
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp: In function 'int wxVsprintf(wchar_t*, const wxString
> &, va_list)':
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:623:47: error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t
> *' to 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
>      return wxCRT_VsprintfW(str, format.wc_str(), argptr);
>                                                ^
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:623:56: error: cannot convert 'va_list {aka char*}' t
> o 'const wchar_t*' for argument '3' to 'int vswprintf(wchar_t*, size_t, const wc
> har_t*, char*)'
>      return wxCRT_VsprintfW(str, format.wc_str(), argptr);
>                                                         ^
> ../../src/common/wxcrt.cpp:632:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void funct
> ion [-Wreturn-type]
>  }
>  ^
> makefile.gcc:6786: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\monodll_wxcrt.o' failed
> mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\monodll_wxcrt.o] Error 1
> ```

Can someone please advice me what more I can do?

Comment: did you run `./configure` to configure the source? (you're supposed to set up unicode,etc. that way instead of manually adding compiler switches)

Comment: @M.M I didn't, but why I should do that? I didn't find any information about it. And second thing is, how am I supposed to run this if I am using Windows, and you wrote it as if I would be using Linux?

Comment: There should be build instructions for your platform

Comment: So there are (multiple) but 1, 2, and 3 (as explained above) doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you speaking about multiple errors, this is clearly one and the same error and is due to using standard-like `vswprintf()` instead of the function from MSVC CRT which is normally used by MinGW by default. The former should only be used when `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` is in effect and it's very strange that you still get it without it, I wonder if you have `CPPFLAGS` or similar set in your environment?

Anyhow, I'd recommend using TDM-GCC 4.9 as 3.1.0 definitely compiles with it (this is what the official binaries have been built with). 4.8 is supposed to work too, of course, so it could be worth checking how is `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` getting defined, but installing 4.9 will probably be simpler for you.